# Why is this code printing "d5" in the second for loop of the getRookMove() function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

void getRookMove(char StartingColumn, int StartingRow) {

    cout << endl;

    for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'h'; ch++) {
        if(ch != StartingColumn) {
            cout << ch << StartingRow << endl;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        if(i != StartingRow - '0') {
            cout << StartingColumn << i << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while(t--) {
        
        string startingPosition;
        cin >> startingPosition;

        getRookMove(startingPosition[0], startingPosition[1] - '0');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to solve this problem [Problem - 1907A - CodeForces](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1907/A).
Another thing I also didn't understand is even though I have already converted the string value into the integer value via the ASCII codes in the main function, why do we still need to do that inside the if statement located in the second for loop of `getRookMove()` function?

Comment: Your question is one more example that code puzzle sites do not teach C++. Use another source of knowledge. [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly said, you already converted the second digit of the starting position to an `int`, so `if(i != StartingRow - '0')` should be `if(i != StartingRow)`.

As regards your question of why `d5` was printed, your original `if` statement was checking if `i != 5 - '0'`, that is `i != 5 - 48`. Obviously all numbers between 1 and 8 match this condition, also when `i == 5` (hence `d5` will be printed).

Comment: Thanks, buddy, for taking your time to help me out.